# !!DEVSTACK!! setup.py is running into a error when run into pbr

Tags: openstack, devstack

so I'm trying to install devstach I followed the instructions from here

```
https://docs.openstack.org/sahara/pike/contributor/devstack.html
```

and this is devstack that I downloaded

```
git clone https://git.openstack.org/openstack-dev/devstack.git
```

and here is my local.conf

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=nova
MYSQL_PASSWORD=nova
RABBIT_PASSWORD=nova
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_TOKEN=nova

# Enable Swift
enable_service s-proxy s-object s-container s-account

SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data

# Force checkout prerequisites
# FORCE_PREREQ=1

# keystone is now configured by default to use PKI as the token format
# which produces huge tokens.
# set UUID as keystone token format which is much shorter and easier to
# work with.
KEYSTONE_TOKEN_FORMAT=UUID

# Change the FLOATING_RANGE to whatever IPs VM is working in.
# In NAT mode it is the subnet VMware Fusion provides, in bridged mode
# it is your local network. But only use the top end of the network by
# using a /27 and starting at the 224 octet.
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.55.224/27

# Enable logging
SCREEN_LOGDIR=$DEST/logs/screen

# Set ``OFFLINE`` to ``True`` to configure ``stack.sh`` to run cleanly
# without Internet access. ``stack.sh`` must have been previously run
# with Internet access to install prerequisites and fetch repositories.
# OFFLINE=True

# Enable sahara
enable_plugin sahara https://git.openstack.org/openstack/sahara

# Enable heat
enable_plugin heat https://git.openstack.org/openstack/heat

# Setting this machine private IP address
HOST_IP="192.168.1.130"
```

But the main problem is after I run **stack.sh** after it goes along and downloads some of the git files like **sahara** & **heat** it will come to this error, to be specific about it here is the error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:                                                        
     command: /usr/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/opt/stack/neutron/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/opt/stack/neutron/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)
(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info
         cwd: /opt/stack/neutron/                                                                         
    Complete output (24 lines):                  
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:634: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'description-file' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'description_fil
e' instead                             
      warnings.warn(     
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:634: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'author-email' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'author_email' inste
ad
      warnings.warn(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:634: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'home-page' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'home_page' instead
      warnings.warn(
    /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py:634: UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'python-requires' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'python_requires'
 instead
      warnings.warn(
    ERROR:root:Error parsing
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/core.py", line 96, in pbr
        attrs = util.cfg_to_args(path, dist.script_args)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/util.py", line 271, in cfg_to_args
        pbr.hooks.setup_hook(config)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/hooks/__init__.py", line 25, in setup_hook
        metadata_config.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/hooks/base.py", line 27, in run
        self.hook()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/hooks/metadata.py", line 25, in hook
        self.config['version'] = packaging.get_version(
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pbr/packaging.py", line 874, in get_version
        raise Exception("Versioning for this project requires either an sdist"
    Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that there is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argu
ment given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name neutron was given, but was not able to be found.
    error in setup command: Error parsing /opt/stack/neutron/setup.cfg: Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. It's also possible that th
ere is a mismatch between the package name in setup.cfg and the argument given to pbr.version.VersionInfo. Project name neutron was given, but was not able to be found.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I check every where that I should check and understood to check. But I think the main problem is related to pbr and the version of it with nutron or something else.

I'm totally new at this so **sorry for not asking this in a better way**

**I'm installing devstack on a ubuntu server 20.04 vm**

Comment: That should rather be a bug report. In order to make it a suitable programming question for SO, you'd have to extract a [mcve] and provide that as part of your question. As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: One thing that sticks out in your local.conf is the token format. UUID has been obsolete for a while. I can't say if that is related to your error, though. I would reinstall that machine to avoid any problems with leftover files from the current failed installation, then try again without that option.

Comment: Another suggestion: Don't clone the master branch, but use a stable one. Add `-b stable/victoria` to `git clone`.